# How to get running DDE servers on the computer

Tags: dde

I want to see a list of all DDE servers (and topics if possible) currently active on my computer. How can I do that? Is there some service started for each DDE server?

I search the Internet and stackoverflow for some time and did not find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Among the tools I use frequently, tcl can do it:

```
dde services {} {}
```

returns all active service-topic pairs.

You can see the implementation in TCL source tree (win/tclWinDde.c). Basically, it's a lot of boring work with windows and messages. First, DDE client window is created. Then WM_DDE_INITIATE is sent to each window (using EnumWindows), passing the client window handle as WPARAM. The client window procedure handles WM_DDE_ACK, adding services and topics from atoms in LOWORD(lParam) and HIWORD(lParam).

Comment: Found also this [DDESpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233534%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) tool from Microsoft.

Comment: I also tried DDESpy, but Tcl/Tk is so simple for this kind of tasks https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dde.htm

Comment: Note that to use the `dde` command you must first `package require dde`.